# bash script count how many regular files and how many directories exist in folder

Tags: linux, bash

Syntax:

```
./count.sh <folder> <depth>
```

Script will search (recursively) starting in `<folder>` up to a depth of `<depth>` levels, and count how many regular files and how many directories exist in that folder. Example: if `<folder>` is `/` and `<depth>` is 2, the program will traverse folder /a/b/* but it will not parse subfolders of `/a/b` (e.g. `/a/b/c/` will NOT be parsed).

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`find "$1" -maxdepth $(($2+1)) -type f | wc -l`

b=`find "$1" -maxdepth $(($2+1)) -type d | wc -l`

b=$(($b-1))

echo  files $a  folders $b
```

Is it ok like this?

Comment: "I have no idea how to do this" . Then you have come to the wrong place for help. S.O. is about helping people fix their broken code. Any code at all is better than none at all. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: i edited my question thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not need a script for that.

To count files :

```
find <folder> -mindepth 1 -maxdepth <depth> -type f | wc -l
```

To count directories :

```
find <folder> -mindepth 1 -maxdepth <depth> -type d | wc -l
```

Notice how this breaks down your problem in two steps : finding all files/directories you are interested in, and piping the results to `wc -l` which just counts lines.

Please note that this method will work most of the time, but would produce erroneous results if there were files or directories with newlines in their names (which is not something you would often see, but is technically possible).  If this is a concern, you could use something like :

```
declare -i i=0
while IFS= read -d '' file
do
    i+=1
done < <(find <folder> -mindepth 1 -maxdepth <depth> -type f -print0)
echo "$i"
```

This uses a zero byte as the separator (which cannot occur in filenames) using the `-print0` option, and `-d ''` option of `read` to use a zero byte as the record separator.

Comment: You don't need to have `-type f` and `-type d` separately? Without `find` can list both by default  in a single command.

Comment: @Inian I think the OP wants to count files and directories separately, but if one wants a single count for everything, one find command can do it.

Comment: Thx for your help and explanations this is exactly what I search for and now I understand how it works :)